# Unable to load asset: /data/user/0/com.example.app/app_flutter/localization/en-IN.json until hot reload

Tags: flutter, localization

I am giving the `ApplicationDocumentsDirectory` path to a localization library called `easy_localization: ^2.3.3`. I used to put locale json files in the Application Directory dynamically at run time so that whenever user changes the language I can call translation API take the result and create json file in Application Directory and change the language using `EasyLocalization.of(context).locale = Locale(langCode, cntryCode);`. But when I close and run the App it shows unable to load asset but when I make a hot reload it will start working perfectly unit next close of the App. In device explorer I can see the locale json files are created in the Application Directory before initializing `EasyLocalization` and starting the App. But unable to load those locale files by easy localization on first run. I am starting my App from `main()` like shown below.

```
  EasyLocalization localization = EasyLocalization(
  path: '$applicationDirPath/localization',
  supportedLocales:  [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('de', 'DE'), Locale('hi', 'IN')],
  fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'IN'),
  child: AppRootWidget());
  runApp(localization);
```

Comment: hi can you please help me how to do this dynamically set the translations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assetLoader` can be used to solve this scenario. Add the property assetLoader to the EasyLocalization as below

```
EasyLocalization localization = EasyLocalization(
  path: 'assets/localization',
  supportedLocales:  [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('de', 'DE'), Locale('hi', 'IN')],
  assetLoader: MyAssetLoader(),
  fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'IN'),
  child: AppRootWidget());
```

you can use any supported asset loaders from the package `easy_localization_loader` or write your own asset loader as shown below.

```
class MyAssetLoader extends AssetLoader {
 
  @override
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> load(String path, Locale locale) async {
            
    //Assuming the source is in english and json
  
      String sourceString = jsonEncode({"welcome": "Welcome","username":"User Name"}); // you can read the base source language from file and assign to sourceString here
      
        if(locale.languageCode == 'ml') // Translation API can be implemented here by passing sourceString                                      
          String translatedRes = jsonEncode({"welcome": "സ്വാഗതം","username":"ഉപയോക്തൃനാമം"}); //Assuming this is the translated response 

       return json.decode(translatedRes);
 
  }
}
```

And create your AssetLoader class as below

```
abstract class AssetLoader {
  const AssetLoader();
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> load(String path, Locale locale);
}
```

Comment: hi can you give me an example of how to do this easy localization with api response